# Cannot get specific information from a database using SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, discord.js

it's my first time making two SQL requests in on 'connection.query' and something is definetly not right, first of all here is my code:

```js
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM custom_prefix WHERE guild_id = '12345678912345678'; SELECT * FROM cache_size`;
    connection.query(sql, async function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        connection.release();
    });
});
```

So far everything works perfectly fine and the output will be:

```js
[
  [
    RowDataPacket {
      prefix: '!',
      guild_id: 12345678912345678,
      guild_name: 'server name',
      changed_by_id: 12345678912345678,
      changed_by_name: 'username#1234',
      changed_date: 2022-04-13T19:50:33.000Z
    }
  ],
  [ RowDataPacket { guilds: 4, users: 39 } ]
]
```

If I change the `console.log(result)` to `console.log(result[1])` the output will be:

```js
[ RowDataPacket { guilds: 4, users: 39 } ]
```

So everything works like I would expect it, but if I only want a specific value from the `result[1]`, lets say the `guilds`, then I would do `console.log(result[1].guilds)`.

I would to this because I have some other files where I check the database for something and use the `result[0].something` method and there it works absolutely fine. But as soon as I use two `SELECT * FROM` requests it doesn't.

So if I try to console.log the `result[1].guilds` the output will be:

```js
undefined
```

Which makes no sense for me because I oftenly use this method and it works fine.
But here it says `undefined`.

So I don't know how to get a specific value from one of the results when using two , I hope somebody here can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, a query result is an array of rows. However, since you performed *multiple* queries, `result` is an array of results of your queries; and each result is an array of rows returned by each query. Thus, you have one more level of nesting than in the scenario where you only have one query.

You are trying to get `.guilds` of an array, which does not have such a property. You want this instead:

```
result[1][0].guilds
```